Firebase Storage error: [firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at desired reference. why that code can't upload images to firebasestore
I am new to work with firebase. ı am treying to develop an app which tere is profe page for users. to get banner iamge from the user ı wrote the code below.

File? _bannerImage;

Future<void> _pickBannerImage() async {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  final pickedFile = await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  if (pickedFile != null) {
    File imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
    setState(() {
      _bannerImage = imageFile;
    });

    User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      String userId = user.uid;
      String filePath = 'bannerImages/$userId/banner.jpg'; // Adjusted path structure

      try {
        // Upload file to Firebase Storage
        TaskSnapshot uploadTask = await FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref(filePath)
            .putFile(imageFile);

        // Get download URL
        String downloadURL = await uploadTask.ref.getDownloadURL();

        // Save download URL in Firestore
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(userId)
            .update({
          'bannerUrl': downloadURL,
        });

        print('Banner image uploaded and URL saved in Firestore');
      } catch (e) {
        print('Error uploading banner image: $e');
      }
    } else {
      print('No user is signed in');
    }
  }
}

this code suppose to let every user can change their banner but, firebase can't download the image. Because of that when ı restart the program, the photo doesn't come.
ı couldn't solve the error
.
the code above every time catches error in try catch.
what should ı do

you can go firebase consolse, in firestore databse, config the rule, i guess that

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Modified firestore rule for your setup:
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /uploads/{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}

Try with this i hope it's useful
HAPPY CODING :)
